# Adding Capital City Markers to a Leaflet Map Using a JS File

Tags: javascript, ajax, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I have created a layer on a leaflet map and have a capitalCities.js file that I want to use to add markers to the map (extract of the capitalCities file is below).

```
let capitals = [{"CountryName":"Somaliland","CapitalName":"Hargeisa","CapitalLatitude":"9.55","CapitalLongitude":"44.050000","CountryCode":"NULL","ContinentName":"Africa"},{"CountryName":"South Georgia and South Sandwich Islands","CapitalName":"King Edward Point","CapitalLatitude":"-54.283333","CapitalLongitude":"-36.500000","CountryCode":"GS","ContinentName":"Antarctica"},{"CountryName":"French Southern and Antarctic Lands","CapitalName":"Port-aux-FranÃƒÂ§ais","CapitalLatitude":"-49.35","CapitalLongitude":"70.216667","CountryCode":"TF","ContinentName":"Antarctica"},
```

What would be the best way to go about this? I'm thinking something like the below ajax request but how do I pass this into a leaflet layers map? I'm declaring the below at the top of the JS file but I think i've been looking at this for too long now:

let capitalCityLat;
let capitalCityLon;

and the ajax request looks like the below but i'm stumped now.

```
 $.ajax({
      url: "js/capitalCities.js",
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
          capital: $('CapitalLatitude', 'CapitalLongitude' ).val()   
      },
      success: function(result) {
```

Any help or direction would be very appriciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to add marker to a Leaflet map would be in the following way:

```
L.marker([50.84673, 4.35247]).addTo(map);
```

In your case, since you are trying to add markers on the basis of the information in the capitals array, you could probably do something like:

```
let capitals = [{"CountryName":"Somaliland","CapitalName":"Hargeisa","CapitalLatitude":"9.55","CapitalLongitude":"44.050000","CountryCode":"NULL","ContinentName":"Africa"},{"CountryName":"South Georgia and South Sandwich Islands","CapitalName":"King Edward Point","CapitalLatitude":"-54.283333","CapitalLongitude":"-36.500000","CountryCode":"GS","ContinentName":"Antarctica"},{"CountryName":"French Southern and Antarctic Lands","CapitalName":"Port-aux-FranÃƒÂ§ais","CapitalLatitude":"-49.35","CapitalLongitude":"70.216667","CountryCode":"TF","ContinentName":"Antarctica"}];


capitals.forEach(capital => {
   L.marker([capital.CapitalLatitude, capital.CapitalLongitude]).addTo(map);
})
```

If you are concerned about accessing the capitals array from another file, you can add a reference to that file in your `index.html` as `<script src="js/capitals.js"></script>`.

And the `capitals` variable will be globally accessible in other scripts too.

Here is an example too: https://codepen.io/dhruvs/pen/jOwVXKv